# How to properly deal with different minor Yii layout variations?

Tags: yii

I have this header that it's fixed across all pages except, the logo. The logo varies a little in color, regarding the page where the user are.

Should we set that on the corresponded controller and call it on the layout.php page ?

```
On controller
public $param = 'logoimagename';

On layout
echo $this->param
```

I've heard that Yii by design doesn't favor this, is there any better way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would implement it using an helper function with a signature like this:

```
function getLogoName($controller, $action, ...){

   $logo = Yii::app()->params['default_logo'];
   $logo_rules = Yii::app()->params['logo_rules'];

   // check if controller and action match any of the logo rules and get the logo name if found; use the default one otherwise

   return $logo;
}
```

The default_logo and the logo_rules are parameters you have to set up in the config files.

In the view files, you could simply write:

```
echo .... getLogoName($this->id, $this->action->id, ...);
```

Comment: Perhaps cleaner indeed. Thanks a lot for sharing it. I was thinking about extending the controller, but a helpers seems much more appropriate.